# How to make reverse scrolling identical as one going to "right" direction on my "Frankensteinian" bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My predicament is how to make slider below carousel slide in similar fashion as from right to left but in reverse style? Slider is activated through carousel arrows. When pressed(right arrow) slider performs flawlessly. But when it's activated by left arrow after going through couple of cycles, it goes haywire ... I know i'm close just need little push in right direction ...

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/veljkos82/t2a0t9tf/94/ and below is code for a function that should control work of left arrow "properly", but it doesn't ... I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2 ..

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="indicatorsofcarousel.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indicatorsofcarousel.css">


</head>
<body>

<div class="container text-center">

  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"><!-- Ako se ukloni .slide klasa onda nema animacije i koliko god da se brzo klikce na strelice karusel i donji slajdovi se savrseno poravnjaju. -->


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div id="pics" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img\img1.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">0</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img2.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">1</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img3.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">2</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img4.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">3</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img5.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">4</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img6.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">5</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img7.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">6</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img8.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">7</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img9.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">8</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img10.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">9</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img11.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">10</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img12.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">11</span>
      </div>

       <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img13.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">12</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img14.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">13</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img15.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">14</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img16.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">15</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img17.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">16</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img18.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">17</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img19.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">18</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img\img20.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">19</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a id="prev" onclick="left()" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a  id="next" onclick="right()" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="pr"></div>
    <div class="lnk">


    <ol id="lista" class="faceless con1">
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img1.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">0</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img2.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">1</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img3.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">2</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img4.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">3</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img5.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">4</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img6.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">5</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img7.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">6</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img8.jpg" alt="Chania"><br><span class="toggle">7</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="8"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img9.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">8</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="9"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img10.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">9</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="10"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img11.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">10</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="11"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img12.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">11</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="12"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img13.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">12</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="13"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img14.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">13</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="14"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img15.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">14</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="15"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img16.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">15</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="16"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img17.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">16</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="17"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img18.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">17</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="18"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img19.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">18</span></a></li>
    <li class="ord_list_elem" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="19"><a href="#"><img class="sl" src="img\img20.jpg" alt="Flower"><br><span class="toggle">19</span></a></li>
    </ol>


    </div>

</div>

</div><br>


</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 720px;
    margin: auto;
}

.tro{
    position: relative;

    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid brown;

    opacity: 0;
}

.sl{    
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;   
}

.sl:hover{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #eaaeae;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #eaaeae;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #eaaeae;
    border: 1px solid brown;
}

.faceless{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.ord_list_elem{
display:inline-block;
}

.con1{
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 720px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*.pr{

    position: absolute;
    top: 670px;
    left: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 720px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}*/

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
```

My js:

```
var clicksRight=0;
        var clicksLeft=0;
        var trini=0;
        var gog=0;
        var pret=0;
        var x=0;
        var y=0;
        var br=0;
        var index=0;
        var currentIndex=0;
        var clicks=0;
        var num=0;
        var mr=0;
        var tmp=0;
        var OldValue = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $( ".sl" ).click(function() { 
    gog=0;
    var width=$( ".sl" ).outerWidth();
    var corr=(width/100)*4.4;
    width+=corr;
    index = $( ".sl" ).index( this ); 
    var count = $('.item').length; 
    var cnt = $('.sl').length;

    document.getElementById("mix1").innerHTML=index;

    if(index!=0){
        currentIndex=index;
        clicksLeft=count-(count-currentIndex);
    }

    if(index>pret){

        if(index==3){
            gog=40;
        }

        if(index>3){
            gog=(width*(index-3))+40;
        }

        $(".con1").animate({scrollLeft: gog});
        pret=index;
    }

    if(index<pret){

        if(index==3){
            gog=40;
        }

        if(index>3){
            gog=(width*(index-3))+40;
        }

        $(".con1").animate({scrollLeft: gog});
        pret=index;
    }


    x=$(".sl").eq(index).offset().top; 
    y=$(".sl").eq(index).offset().left; 

    br=$(".con1").scrollLeft();
    clicksLeft=count-index;

});


});



function right(){
    gog=0;
    br=$(".con1").scrollLeft();
    var width=$( ".sl" ).outerWidth();
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
    var count = $('.item').length; 
    var cnt = $('.sl').length;
    var corr=(width/100)*4.4;
    width+=corr;
    var p1=document.getElementById("lista").scrollWidth;
    var p2=$("#lista").outerWidth();
    var p3=p1-p2;
    clicksRight+=1;

    if(br==0 && currentIndex>2){
        gog=br+((width-15)/2);
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog); 
    }

    if(br>0){
        gog=br+width;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
    }

    if(br==p3 && currentIndex==count){
        gog=0;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        clicksRight=0;
    }

    clicksLeft=count-currentIndex;
    document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML=clicksLeft;
    document.getElementById("mix1").innerHTML=currentIndex;


}


function left(){
    gog==0;
    br=$(".con1").scrollLeft();
    var width=$( ".sl" ).outerWidth();
    var count = $('.item').length; 
    var cnt = $('.sl').length;
    var corr=(width/100)*4;
    width+=corr;
    var p1=document.getElementById("lista").scrollWidth;
    var p2=$("#lista").outerWidth();
    var p3=p1-p2;
    clicksLeft+=1;

    if(br==0 && clicksLeft==1){
        gog=p3;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        //alert("1");
        currentIndex=count;
    }

    if(clicksLeft>4 && br==p3){
        gog=br-width;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        //alert("2");
    }

    if(clicksLeft>4){
        gog=br-width;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        //alert("3");
    }

    if(currentIndex==0 && clicksRight>0){ 
        gog=p3;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        //alert("4");
    }

    if(clicksLeft>4 && clicksRight>0){ 
        gog=br-width;
        $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
        //alert("5");
    }


    if(clicksRight>0){
        currentIndex-=1;    
        //alert("6");
    }

    if(clicksRight==0 && currentIndex>=0){
        currentIndex=count-clicksLeft;  
        //alert("7");
    }

    if(currentIndex==count && clicksLeft){
            gog=p3;
            $(".con1").scrollLeft(gog);
            //alert("8");
    }

    if(currentIndex==0){
        clicksLeft=0;
        //alert("9");
    }


    document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML=clicksLeft;
    document.getElementById("mix1").innerHTML=currentIndex;
}




function funk(){
    var brt = $("#lista").find('img.sl:first'); // Ili var brt = $("#lista").find('img.sl') => brt[0]
    var count = $('.item').length; 

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="br: "+br+"px, currentIndex: "+currentIndex+", clicksLeft: "+clicksLeft;
}

function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("lista");
    var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
    document.getElementById ("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Your images are not visible. Why are you counting clicks? 
Seems to me like right arrow is not working properly, too. Make sure that you set all the CSS properties of your elements, to be sure not to have any values that could potentially mess up the layout (margins, padding, borders). For example, when clicking on right arrow I noticed that most-right thumbnail is not always on the same distance from the right margin of the wrapper element. That could be indicator that distance you calculated to move the slider is not correct (probably because of some pixel or two of margin or padding).

Comment: Edited. All margin are set to auto and css only have one padding-top that only affect height, but i dont need height since slider is horizontal. Dont know how you dont see images ... I see them perfectly even if i logout from jsfiddle ... I also noticed a problem in jsfiddle that doesn't occur in my script running from localhost. Dont know why is this happening but it does. Ps: I used variable which accept value from  outerWidth(true) so that "incremental" value to move slider. On top of that i also added additional 9px as correction, but 'desyncing' still persists. Dont know what else to do

Comment: Just add i use XAMPP v3.2.2 and in it everything except left arrow is working perfectly. I dont know why is this happening in jsfiddle or are these inconsistencies inherent to it ...

Comment: 9px in jsfiddle, 5px in actual js as can be seen.

Comment: Well, you are logged in to your Dropbox account, that's why you see the images and I don't :)

Comment: Well, i "logout-ed" from dropbox, SO and jsfiddle and my fiddle still works as i described earlier i.e. does show images and left arrow "throwing tantrums" ... I dont why is this happening to everybody else ..

Comment: I tested and it works only in Chrome(for now). But before i make it work in other browsers, first i have to make it work perfectly in this one(Chrome) ..

Comment: Currently only works in Chrome, Opera and Safari and not in FF. JSfiddle only works in Chrome and Opera ... When i make left arrow working in at least one of the browsers, then i'll make whole thing to work in others. As for code in jsfiddle not working proper, who the hell knows. At least it's better then yesterday ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no element with id `mix1`, that's why javascript gets error and breaks.

Here's working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez11Lvc1/26/) with commented `mix1` lines.

```
function left() {

      if (index != clicks) {
        index = clicks;
      }
      clicks += 1;
      //document.getElementById("mix1").innerHTML = clicks;
      var gog1 = 0;
      var brt = $("#lista").find('img.sl:first');
      //(brt.offset().left==152 || brt.offset().left==55)
      var bry = $("#lista").find('img.sl:last');

      if (clicks > 4) {
        gog1 = $(".con1").scrollLeft() - 105;
        $(".con1").animate({
          scrollLeft: gog1
        });
      }



      if (($(".con1").scrollLeft()) == 0) {

        gog1 = 1396;
        $(".con1").animate({
          scrollLeft: gog1
        });

      }

      //document.getElementById("mix1").innerHTML = clicks;

    }
```

Comment: I'm new to jsfiddle, but at last i edited it? Anyhow, now performs just like on my webserver.(minus)-little alignment problems ... But my main problem still persists. After first cycle of clicking on left arrow, every subsequent one(second, third ...) slider goes little more then it should. How to sync slider regardless of number of cycle? Sorry to you all for my bad incoherent english, but i'm trying to solve this problem 15+ hours straight ..